# VSTS How to create package file (zip) with multi project solution

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops

We have a solution with two web projects:

Solution ->
  - Project 1
  - Project 2

We have a CI in VSTS that build and create the package (artifact zip file).

When we added a second project in the solution, the artifact only has one project. Checking the logs in VSTS we have seen these lines:

`2018-08-21T13:27:55.6971077Z CleanWebsitesPackageCore:
2018-08-21T13:27:55.6971269Z   Deleting file "D:\a\1\a\20180821.17.zip".
2018-08-21T13:27:55.6997562Z CleanWebsitesPackage:
2018-08-21T13:27:55.6997903Z   Deleting file "D:\a\1\a\20180821.17.SourceManifest.xml".
2018-08-21T13:27:55.7002478Z   Deleting file "D:\a\1\a\20180821.17.deploy.cmd".
2018-08-21T13:27:55.7006495Z   Deleting file "D:\a\1\a\20180821.17.deploy-readme.txt".
2018-08-21T13:27:55.7009652Z   Deleting file "D:\a\1\a\20180821.17.SetParameters.xml".
2018-08-21T13:27:55.7022918Z ValidateGlobalPackageSetting:
2018-08-21T13:27:55.7023199Z   $(PackageAsSingleFile) is true
2018-08-21T13:27:55.7023978Z   $(PackageFileName) is D:\a\1\a\20180821.17.zip. Validating...
2018-08-21T13:27:55.7028185Z CollectFilesFromIntermediateAssembly:`

Seems that VSTS when finishes the first project, remove the zip files and starts the next one.

I have found a workaround defining the target project name (defining -t):

`/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\$(Build.BuildNumber).zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Web Site" /p:ProductsToRelease="Frontend" /t:Frontend\Frontend`

If I executed the msbuild in my computer, the zip file has the two project in but in VSTS is not working.

Is there any configuration to avoid that remove target (CleanWebsitesPackageCore)?

Comment: What if you use two MSBuild task instead  a VS Build task to build the two projects separately? And specify different `/p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation` for the two MSBuild task, such as one  for `/p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\app1`, and the other for `/p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\app2`.

Comment: Actually, the workaround that we are using is building the two projects separately, but we are building several times, e.g: integration tests, project 1, project 2. We have some shared code between project 1 and project 2.Before we built in one step (run test and create the artifact after build step).

Answer (score 1):

For me in my .sln I had 4 csproj's that should have added to the webapp.zip.

In two of those projects this resulted in CleanWebsitesPackageCore being called resulting in the same issue you have.

I "fixed" by adding the following empty targets to bottom of the the 2 offending csproj's file, which overrides the normal clean functionality:

```xml
 <Target Name="CleanWebsitesPackageCore"/>
  <Target Name="CleanWebsitesPackage"/>
```